# xpath of same sibling under li tag if no identifiers present

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to get the value of div tag under the label "Date of Joining" , 
i.e I need the value "06/06/2009"
I can go upto the label with text "date of joining", but how to get the text of div under the tag Label".
Following is html code -

```
<div class="employee_highlight" style="background-color: transparent;">
<ul class="employee_highlight_layout">
<li>
<li>
<li>
    <div class="column_left">
        <label for="Department" style="background-color: transparent;">Date of Joining</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column_right" nowrap="nowrap">06/06/2009</div>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly fetch the text this way:

```
String doj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Date of Joining')]//div[2]")).getText();
```

or

```
String doj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(.,'Date of Joining')]//div[@class='column_right']")).getText();
```

Comment: +1 for the second xpath, as it is identifying each element in its path by some sort of logical function.

Answer (score -1):

You must have stored element for text 'Date of Joining', let's say it is `element`. Now, we can find the element with text '06/06/2009' with following:

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("..//following-sibling::div")).getText();
```

Comment: Actually the li contains 2 div tags, 1st div tag label I can get with text "date of joining", now I want the value of the 2nd div tag under the li where the value is "date of joining", I just want the date of joining for each employee, I can reach upto the date of joining field, now I want the value, hope my question is clear now.

Comment: Please see updated answer. That will return value `06/06/2009`

Comment: Great it worked, would you please explain the statement "..//following-sibling::div"?

Comment: Here, we're finding element with respect to `element` hence we used `element.findElement...` In our case, `element` is with `label` tag and `Date of Joining` text. Now, let's move to understanding of `..//following-sibling::div` Here, `..` refers to parent element of current element(which is with `div` tag i.e. parent div of label) and `following-sibling::div` means element with `div` tag which is following sibling of `div`(which we found earlier using `..`)

Comment: I tried to combine the 2 xpath into one like this -
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='employee_highlight']//label[text()='Date of Joining']..//following-sibling::div")).getText()
but this is not working in my case, would you please help me if this is wrong?

Comment: You're missing `/` after `label[text()='D‌​ate of Joining']` and there are two `/` before `following-sibling::div` rather there should be only one `/`. Corrected is: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='employee_highlight']//label[text()='D‌​ate of Joining']/../following-sibling::div")).getText();` Still, I'm not sure if this works because I think we're looking for element in 3rd `li`. Let me know if above doesn't work and the element we're looking for is in 3rd `li` I'll send you correct xpath.

Comment: great! this worked for me and saves some lines of code.